# How to post values from form1 to form2 with asp

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have 2 webforms.  The first one Webform1.aspx collects the data entered by the user and post it to the second form Webform2.asp. The second form has 3 textboxes , once the user enters the data in the first webform , the values should be passed to the second form so that each textbox will hold the value the user entered from the first form.

I tried it with  for the second form, but im getting

Message 1   Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'value' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'.  C:\Users\Owner\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\ajaxcall1\ajaxcall1\WebForm2.asp   11  51  ajaxcall1

Webform1.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>  </title>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >

        var f = $("#myForm");  
        var url = f.attr("action");  //loads the url from the form with id myForm action="/Home/FormPost" so url = action="/Home/FormPost", 
        // by calling this jquery it will navigate to the controller action="/Home/FormPost"
        // which will post Bob Cravens (43) has been saved.

        var formData = f.serialize();   // loads the data entered from the form 
        $.post(url, formData, function (data) {
            $("#postResult").html(data);
        });


    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <form id="myForm" action="Webform2.asp" method="post">
    <div>First Name: <input name="FirstName" type="text" value="Bob" /></div>
    <div>Last Name: <input name="LastName" type="text" value="Cravens" /></div>
    <div>Age: <input name="Age" type="text" value="43" /></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save Contact" />
    <div id="postResult">?</div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Webform2.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method ="post" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" value =""></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" value =""></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" value =""></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>

     <%


response.write(request.querystring("FirstName"))
response.write(" " & request.querystring("LastName"))


        fname = request.querystring("FirstName")
        lname =  request.querystring("LastName")

response.write("<p>Hello " & fname & " " & lname & "!</p>")
response.write("<p>Welcome to my Web site!</p>")


         %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Message 1 Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'value' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'.

[MSDN `TextBox` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Long story short the `<asp:TextBox />` tag doesn't have a value attribute. That is why when you try to put it on the tag, the aspx engine gets all in a tizzy.

*Edit:*

It does have a `Text` Property, which you can see more about [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This shouldn't be caused by your cross page posting, but if still have problems there please ask another question.